# Как сверстать блоки с фото в html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка, figma

[Как сверстать данные блоки в html?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTEeU.jpg)

[image: и этот]

Comment: а где ваши попытки решения?

Answer (score 4):

Пример

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.timeline {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 2rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  gap: 4rem 2rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.timeline__item {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.timeline__circle {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  border: 10px solid #BD4A4E;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 2rem;
  position: relative;
}

.timeline__circle::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -1rem;
  left: -1rem;
  bottom: -1rem;
  right: -1rem;
  border: 1px dotted #BD4A4E;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.timeline__line {
  display: block;
  width: 1px;
  height: 40px;
  border-left: 1px dotted #BD4A4E;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  margin-top: .5rem;
}

.timeline__line::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -.25rem;
  left: 50%;
  width: .5rem;
  height: .5rem;
  background-color: #BD4A4E;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.timeline__arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 85%;
  width: 70%;
  height: 1px;
  border-top: 1px dotted #BD4A4E;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.timeline__item:nth-of-type(even) {
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

.timeline__item:nth-of-type(even) .timeline__line {
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.timeline__item:nth-of-type(even) .timeline__line::after {
  bottom: auto;
  top: -.25rem;
}

.timeline__item:nth-of-type(even) .timeline__arrow {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline">
  <div class="timeline__item">
    <div class="timeline__circle">1</div>
    <div class="timeline__line"></div>
    <div class="timeline__text">Text<br> text</div>
    <div class="timeline__arrow"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline__item">
    <div class="timeline__circle">2</div>
    <div class="timeline__line"></div>
    <div class="timeline__text">Text<br> text</div>
    <div class="timeline__arrow"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline__item">
    <div class="timeline__circle">3</div>
    <div class="timeline__line"></div>
    <div class="timeline__text">Text<br> text</div>
    <div class="timeline__arrow"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline__item">
    <div class="timeline__circle">4</div>
    <div class="timeline__line"></div>
    <div class="timeline__text">Text<br> text</div>
    <div class="timeline__arrow"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline__item">
    <div class="timeline__circle">5</div>
    <div class="timeline__line"></div>
    <div class="timeline__text">Text<br> text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```